# NodeJS Jade upload file

Tags: pug

Folks, the following code throws an error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

jade:

```
input#fileupload(type='file', name='files[]', data-url='/upload', multiple='multiple')


script.
    $(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: do you have this code somewhere? `child_proc.spawn`?

Comment: i dont, man, i wish this was easier for a non-webdev like me :)

Comment: is jade properly installed? check you node_modules... Also the code doesn't seem to be related to the error. The error is spawn with childprocess. there must be code like `child_proc.spawn` somewhere.

Comment: jade is working fine, ie its rendering the rest of pages

Comment: are you running windows? what version of node are you running `node -v`?

Comment: i dont know windows, fortunately :)  `v0.10.23`

Comment: Also, the file DOES end up on the file system.  However the thread crashes afterwards.  I've tried to comment out the document.body line as well.. really at a loss here folks

Comment: Maybe you should be showing your controller code instead, specifically after upload. :)

Comment: I've copied the work here: `https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware`

Comment: are you using the example given?

Comment: absolutely, using the most basic i can throw at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said on the examples [here](https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware/tree/master/examples) and from what you said that the server fails after uploading.

I assume that this has something to do with processing the image after upload, possibly resizing the image.

Which requires the ImageMagick to be installed on your system to run the command `$ convert`.

found on `lib/uploadHandler.js`

```
imageMagick.resize({
   width: opts.width,
   height: opts.height,
   srcPath: options.uploadDir() + '/' + fileInfo.name,
   dstPath: options.uploadDir() + '/' + version + '/' + dstName,
   customArgs: opts.imageArgs || ['-auto-orient']
}, finish);
```

So please do a,

```
yum install ImageMagick
```

for CentOS, or for Ubuntu/Debian

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```